# Alternative of OFFSET statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-injection

I'm trying SQL injection in a private bug bounty program. The login panel has a SQL injection vulnerable and the server is SQL Server 2008.

So I injected a query which was :

```
UNION

SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, (SELECT Distinct TABLE_NAME AS 'data()' 
                  FROM information_schema.TABLES 
                  FOR XML PATH(''))), 2, 3
```

It prints table name with in the error page. But the problem is that is prints only 2048 byte. So I can't get all the table names. But I need to fetch all the tables. So I tried with the limit and offset statement.

It didn't work as it is not supported by SQL Server 2008. Is there any way to print out all the tables?

Comment: I'm not sure I really like the idea of giving an answer to help a New Contributor inject into a system (even if they say it's for a bounty program).

Comment: I'm securing a system,  isnt it?  

Comment: My point is that I don't know you, @ABDSHALEH, and as a New Contributor you don't have any past reputation to show you are a trusted person. I'm not saying that you aren't to be trust, but I don't know that and I would hate for advice I gave on injection to be used maliciously. I, personally, don't feel comfortable giving someone new, and a stranger, information on how to successfully compromise a system and I imagine many others here won't either. This doesn't make this a bad question (especially if you doing this legally), but it raises ethical concerns for the users you're asking help from.

Comment: *Apologies for some of the broken English above, I was at the character limit, so cut some words out to fit.*

Comment:  Well,  Can you just tell.me if there are any alternative of limit and offset statement?

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 you would have been limited to using `TOP` (but that would only give you the first rows, doesn't help with offsetting) or row numbering.

Comment: How exactly do you hack a database engine if you don't know the features available with the version you are attempting to exploit? In addition, I would expect someone attempt this to also have the knowledge to simply search the web for suggestions about the equivalent functionality.

Comment: Like this one - [offset fetch in 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/offset-fetch-in-sql-server-2008)